# mysql jdbc multi update return wrong affected rows

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
    String sql = "update t_test set createDate = now() where id = 1; update t_test set createDate = now() where id = 101;";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&allowMultiQueries=true&useSSL=false";
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username", "password");
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    final PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    preparedStatement.execute();
    //return 1, but 2 rows actually updated
    System.out.println("updated rows=" + preparedStatement.getUpdateCount());
    connection.commit();
    connection.close();
```

table `t_test` contains two columns: `id` and `createDate`, I set `allowMultiQueries=true` in jdbc url.
In the above sql, two rows are updated, but `preparedStatement.getUpdateCount()` returns 1.
MySQL server version is 5.7, I have tested with jdbc driver version 5.1.40, 6.0.6 and 8.0.21, they all return same result:1

`EDIT`:
As @Massimo said, I use `getMoreResults()` and `getUpdateCount()` repeatedly to get updated count and sum them up until `getUpdateCount()` returns -1.

Code is below:

```
    System.out.println("updated rows=" + preparedStatement.getUpdateCount());
    int totalCount = preparedStatement.getUpdateCount();
    while (true){
        preparedStatement.getMoreResults();
        final int updateCount = preparedStatement.getUpdateCount();
        if(updateCount != -1){
            System.out.println("updated rows=" + preparedStatement.getUpdateCount());
            totalCount += preparedStatement.getUpdateCount();
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("total updated rows=" + totalCount);
```

Comment: When you use multi-queries, likely it returns the update count of the first (or possibly the last) update executed. Don't use multi-queries. It is a non-standard extension of the JDBC API.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel,  getUpdateCount() returns the first statement result. corrent way to solve this problem is written at the EDIT part of OP. Tks all the same.

Comment: Good to hear you have a solution, but nevertheless, executing multiple queries in one execute is not how JDBC is meant to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot test it.
However in theory, as you are executing multiple statements, the `preparedStatement` gets back the updateCount of each one.
So it's giving the update count of the first statement. To get the update count of the second you should try calling `preparedStatement.getMoreResults()` and then `preparedStatement.getUpdateCount()` again.

see docs

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getUpdateCount()

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getMoreResults()

Comment: tks very much. I tak your advice and write code in EdIT part of the OP, it works.